# Python subprocess introduces spaces

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I've a python script that uses subprocess.Popen to execute Windows *.exe files. All EXEs except one produce expected output. When printed using print() the output in question includes whitespace between every character of the output.

This is how the output looks when executing the EXE in Windows command line:

```
C:\Python27>autorunsc.exe /accepteula

Sysinternals Autoruns v13.51 - Autostart program viewer
Copyright (C) 2002-2015 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Wds\rdpwd\StartupPrograms
   rdpclip
     rdpclip
     RDP Clip Monitor
     Microsoft Corporation
     6.1.7601.17514
     c:\windows\system32\rdpclip.exe
     20/11/2010 11:22

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit
   C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe
```

This is how it looks when printed in Python:

```
Sysinternals Autoruns v13.51 - Autostart program viewer
Copyright (C) 2002-2015 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


 H K L M \ S y s t e m \ C u r r e n t C o n t r o l S e t \ C o n t r o l \
 r m i n a l   S e r v e r \ W d s \ r d p w d \ S t a r t u p P r o g r a m
       r d p c l i p
           r d p c l i p
           R D P   C l i p   M o n i t o r
           M i c r o s o f t   C o r p o r a t i o n
           6 . 1 . 7 6 0 1 . 1 7 5 1 4
           c : \ w i n d o w s \ s y s t e m 3 2 \ r d p c l i p . e x e
           2 0 / 1 1 / 2 0 1 0   1 1 : 2 2

 H K L M \ S O F T W A R E \ M i c r o s o f t \ W i n d o w s   N T \ C u r
 n t V e r s i o n \ W i n l o g o n \ U s e r i n i t
```

We can clearly see the whitespace and what's interesting is that the first few lines don't include the spaces.

This is the code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('autorunsc.exe /accepteula', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
a=p.stdout.read()
print(a)
```

Where does the spaces come from and how do I remove them?

Comment: The most likely obvious answer is that it's a result of Microsoft tooling using UTF-16 rather than UTF-8 internally.

Comment: Are they really 0x20 ASCII spaces, as opposed to NULs? I'd hazard the latter.

Comment: What happens when you ignore `stderr` (don't route it to `STDOUT`)

Comment: BTW, this is a very Windows-specific question, so I'd suggest adjusting the title and tagging appropriately.

Comment: @MartinKonecny, I'd be *astonished* if there were literal spaces going to stderr interleaved with content characters going out stdout. There's no reason for it to be the case, whereas there's every reason for there to be literal NULs interleaved with ASCII characters in the output (since UTF-16 is the native format that Microsoft uses for their registry strings and otherwise the content at question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows tools output format is encoded in UTF-16.

You have to decode output to correct encoding using [str.decode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) method. Quoting docs:

> `str.decode([encoding[, errors]])`
>
> Decodes the string using the codec registered for encoding. encoding
>   defaults to the default string encoding. errors may be given to set a
>   different error handling scheme. The default is 'strict', meaning that
>   encoding errors raise UnicodeError. Other possible values are
>   'ignore', 'replace' and any other name registered via
>   codecs.register_error(), see section Codec Base Classes.

```
a=p.stdout.read().decode('UTF16')
```

For table of standard encodings you may refer to [7.8.3. Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Since your output seems to have mixed encoding [as "spaces" (which are really `0x00` characters, not `0x20`) exists only in part of output], you may want to preprocess or partition your string before performing decoding.

Comment: This works! There were the \0x00 chars in the output. the .decode('UTF16') did the trick. I don't need the first chunk of the output and it's always fixed length so I just print the slice I need. Thanks